# PhoneGap doesnt trigger error callback on 401 error

Tags: angularjs, cordova, oauth, http-headers

I am using PhoneGap in one of my mobile app, using AngularJS and Ionic framework.
I have implemented OAuth 2.0, successfully getting access_token and all.
But while calling any Google API, It doesnt trigger error callback on 401 error code.

```
 $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo').success(function (data, status) {
    console.log('success call userinfo ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(data);
}).error(function (error) {
    console.log('error call userinfo ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    console.log(data);
});
```

However in code, success callback is always called whether it 200,404,401 HTTP codes.

How can I overcome this problem? I want to intercept error callback and do something, while on fiddle, same code runs successfully. I think PhoneGap is appending something to headers.

PS: I have added < access uri="*" subdomains="true" /> to config.xml too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, Seems like problem was with AngularJS version 1.2.2, Now upgraded to AngularJS 1.2.9, Working fine.

Comment: You're getting 401's back? Seems contrary to everything I've read on Cordova/PhoneGap...